# Parse with Swift: handle network error manually

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, networking

I have been trying to modify the following code to manually handle network errors (e.g. disconnection) when retrieving users (`_User` table) from Parse. As soon as the error returned from the PFQuery is not nil, I should return the `completionHandler` with the ***errorMsg***, however, the following code doesn't seem to return. Instead the Parse SDK error message keeps printing:

```
var status: Bool = false
        var errorMsg: String? = nil

        var query = PFQuery(className: ParseClient.ClassNames.User) //default limit - 100
        query.whereKey("email", containsString: "@").findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {                
                status = true
                didComplete(success: status, students: objects as! [PFUser], error: nil)
                return

            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("error in fetching all users from Parse")
                    errorMsg = "There are network problems in fetching user data, please try again later."
                    didComplete(success: status, students: nil, error: errorMsg)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
```

**Parse network error message:**

```
2015-09-01 21:28:59.881 UserGame[3564:354410] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 3 after sleeping for 5.993194 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `return` is inside your `dispatch_async` block, and I think you meant to put it outside.

That said, I'm pretty sure you can't stop Parse from retrying, at least not from within this block. You could also try:

```
query.cancel()
```

This "cancels the current network request (if any)."

Comment: Thanks. I found the 3rd party library Reachability very helpful: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift . That being said, I will try your suggestion when I have time. Thanks so much!